# CSS: revoke transparent color from parent

Tags: html, css, transparency

I've got an image background in my `#wrapper` div and a 33% transparent white color "overlay" in the `#lightbackground` div (`background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);`). Now I want to revoke this transparent white color in the `#footer` div which is placed over the `#lightbackground` div:

[image]

The result should be something like that:

[image]

The position of the `#footer` div (depending y axis) is unknown! It's depending on the content shown in the `#content` div. The minimum height should be as large, that the `#footer` div is at the bottom of the html.

I used this trick to prevent the footer from beeing displayed at the middele of the page: http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/. The problem is, that the `wrapper` and the `lightbackground` start after the header and end with the page. So they are also over my footer (as shown in the first picture). But I want the footer to have the original background image without any white overlay (see image 2).

Here's a simplified version of my project: https://jsfiddle.net/mab30m0e/ take a look at the comments in the js section!

One of my thoughts was to set the background image again to the `#footer` div, but it would have to be placed like the one in the `#wrapper` div and only the part of the background that's inside of the `#footer` div should show up.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Can the size and position of div2 vary?

Comment: No can do. If the parent transparency level is 50%, then the child, at 100% is still only 50% transparent. And 200% is an invalid value.

Comment: @BoltClock the position does, the size is constant

Comment: Any chance you could show us your existing HTML and CSS at all? This can help narrow down possible answers.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, I think that would be an good idea. I just have to simplify it a little, give me 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the "content" size problem with CSS3 `calc`:

```
CSS

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #FFFF33;
    background-image: url(http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02625/mountain1_2625884k.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: right top;
}
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
#lightbackground {
    /* Actually height works for me here, but perhaps my case's simpler */
    min-height: calc(100% - 160px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#content {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
/* This has much in common with #header */
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the same HTML you're using now. You do have the trouble of updating the "160px" to always be the sum of heights of header and footer, and you might find [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) useful for this.

Comment: would you update my jsfiddle, I don't know how to apply this changes.

Comment: I have tried but it did not work (the content div did not auto-scroll). I placed the code here if you need it - http://www.serni.org/fiddle/armin and http://www.serni.org/fiddle/armin/1.html . Tested only with Firefox, later I'll check with other browsers.

Comment: Hey nice solution! With a few changes it works perfect: use `min-height: calc(100% - 160px);` istead of `height: calc(100% - 160px);` so it expands if the content is larger; Set the background in `html, body` so it fits the whole page. Please try it and update your Answer. Thanks

Comment: Updated answer. I had placed height instead of min-height because I believed you wanted to fill the viewport; for the same reason I used the overflow-y scrolling. For your original question (you had header of 100px, footer of 80px) the numbers ought to be 180, 100, 80, and the #header and #footer classes aren't exactly identical.

Comment: Thanks, I updated this to be the answer because it has better browser compatibility than the flexbox solution and it's easier to use / less code. Great job ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**

Based on your edits and the fiddle you provided, I think this is a good job for Flexbox:

1. set the body to have at least the height of the viewport with `min-height: 100vh`
2. make the header and footer non-flex with a fixed height of 80px with `flex: 0 0 80px`
3. let `<main>` soak up the rest of the available space with `flex: 1 1 auto`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: url(//placekitten.com/g/600/600) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

header, footer, main {
  text-align: center;
}

header, footer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 80px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 80px;
  flex: 0 0 80px;
}

main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.33);
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>I'm the header. Yay!</header>
<main>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>I'm the content</h1>
    <p>asdfasdfasdf adsfasdfasdf asdfadfasdf adfasdfasdf</p>
    <p>asdfasdfasdf adsfasdfasdf asdfadfasdf adfasdfasdf</p>
    <p>asdfasdfasdf adsfasdfasdf asdfadfasdf adfasdfasdf</p>
    <p>asdfasdfasdf adsfasdfasdf asdfadfasdf adfasdfasdf</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>I'm the footer. Bye!</footer>
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this in a view minutes

Comment: *few; That would probably be a "horrible hack" for my originally desriped problem, but i discriped it wrong. take a look at the jsfiddle link I just added. If I would use this realy horrible solution, I would need sth like a min-height-position as the box without the white is in fact my footer...

Comment: @Armin Sorry, I don't understand, and looking at your fiddle does not help either?

Comment: take a look at the informaion I added to my question (EDIT3). Then you'll understand the main idea behind this project.

Comment: @Armin so what you are actually trying to achieve has nearly nothing to do with your original question :) Could you please clean the question up and remove the wrong information?

Comment: @Armin I've updated my answer and provided a new fiddle.

Comment: I've cleaned my question. Your new solution has the problem, that the footer is placed after the content ends, and if the content is (e.g.) just one line, the footer shows in the middle of the page.

Comment: @Armin thanks. Can the markup be changed, and what browser versions have to be supported?

Comment: Do you have a different solution in mind? browser version is not that important for me.

Comment: @Armin cool! In that case, let's use some shiny CSS3 with Flexbox! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, looks great. One more question: Would you use flexbox for a homepage?

Comment: @Armin that always depends on the audience and the purpose of the site. If by 'homepage' you mean 'personal site', then yeah, it should be fine. If it would be a site selling services to enterprise customers that are still stuck on IE8, not so much. It's always a good idea to install analytics such as Google Analytics, and to check regularly what browsers your audience uses.

Answer (score 2):

So I came up with an absolute horrible solution for you. I load the background twice and then move it accordingly in the "clear" div.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
}
#one {
  background: url('http://www.freefoto.com/images/12/13/12_13_4---Flowers-in-a-Garden-Border_web.jpg');
  position: relative;
}
#two {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#three {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  background: url('http://www.freefoto.com/images/12/13/12_13_4---Flowers-in-a-Garden-Border_web.jpg');
  background-position: -50px -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8oeurh3p/) with the code.

The key here is background-position. Set the clear div's dimensions and position and then move the background image. Remember to move the background image in the opposite direction that you moved your clear div. Hence the negative numbers on background-position.

Good luck, I really hope you find a better solution then this.

Comment: So, now there's just one more problem: the position of `<div id="three">` varies. I don't know the `background-position` in context of div3. It would be the position (0,0) from the div1 or div2 context.

Answer (score 2):

Since height of header and footer is known, it is easy to draw an opaque overlay over the background image, like this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font: medium sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .33), rgba(255, 255, 255, .33)) no-repeat left 100px/100% calc(100% - 100px - 150px),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhcrj.jpg) left top /cover;
}
#header {
  height: 100px;
}
#content {
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">header - fixed height</div>
  <div id="content">content - auto height</div>
  <div id="footer">footer - fixed height + sticky</div>
</div>
```

**Original Answer ([see question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28514688/1))**

You need one div with a background image and multiple opaque background images:

```css
#bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,.3)) no-repeat left  top    / 100% 50px,
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,.3)) no-repeat left  bottom / 100% 50px,
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,.3)) no-repeat left  50px   / 50px calc(100% - 50px - 50px),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,.3)) no-repeat right 50px   / 50px calc(100% - 50px - 50px),
    url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-8.jpg) left top / cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
```

Comment: I had to open the preview in full screen to figure out what I was supposed to be looking at.

Comment: same problem here: the position of the "no-transparent-white-area" varies in y axis

Comment: @armin could you explain the issue? It is easy to play with the numbers. or you could use percentage values instead of hardcoded 100px.

Comment: Take a look at my question again, I've updated it, the former one didn't point out my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining:

```
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/BrianDGLS/pen/zxRPMd

Comment: I think you missunderstood the problem. that sqare that is black at your example should be tranparent, so that the background without the 30% transparent white is shown. Please read my original post again. But thanks for your effort ;)

Comment: The area without the 30% white overlay is'nt centered. I also don't know it's postion on y axis - it depends on the content